# Passing on the value CSS variable to SASS variable

Tags: sass

When you assign a scss variable to an existing css variable like this

```
--color: #FFF;
$color: var(--color);
```

This will result in $color holding the var(--color) as a value. Is there a trick so it would hold the actual CSS value? So $color would save the #FFF?

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable like this

```
$color: #FFF;
```

and use it like this for example

```
p {
  color: $color;
}
```

Comment: That I know, but the question is about interacting with css and sass variables. I am using both, css globally and sass in local files to use them with custom functions. Thats why I would like to pass on the value.

Comment: You must have a variables.scss or something like that and you must import it in your index.scss for making tha variables globally

Comment: I know that too, i have variables.scss with a bunch of css variables `--var`. On component files i want to transfer the value of that `--var` to a sass $variable so i can use the sass functions on it.